# Sql query in drupal module - what is node?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal-7

I am running the following query which returns an array of stcClass objects as below:

```
 $result = db_query('SELECT node.title AS node_title, 
                   node.nid AS nid, 
                   node.created AS node_created, 
                   \'node\' AS field_data_my_field_node_entity_type 
                   FROM {node} node WHERE (( (node.status = :status) 
                   AND (node.type IN  (:type)) )) 
                   ORDER BY node_created DESC', 
                   array(':status'=>'1', ':type'=>'_my_content_type'));


stdClass Object
(
[node_title] => my sample title
[nid] => 331
[node_created] => 1367500781
[field_data_my_field_node_entity_type] => node
)
```

It returns an array of stdClass objects.  My problem is that in the field 'field_data_my_field_node_entity_type' I have only the string 'node' because this is passed into the query as a string.  I don't really know much about this, but I suppose I can get a value there if I have the correct syntax.

Any idea how this query is supposed to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your issue? field_data_my_field_node_entity_type = 'node' because it's what the query do...

Comment: But why is node just a string?  Can't I get a value for that field?  i took the query from views and am trying to understand it.  Thanks

Comment: if you want another value you have to change \'node\' by something else like node.the_field_you_want

Comment: I want the value of that field, not a string called 'node' - am i doing something wrong, or is that just how the query is supposed to work?

Comment: what are the fields of your table node? in this state your query will always return the string 'node' for this field. if you want the entity type and if there is a column named entity_type in your table replace \'node\' by node.entity_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that value because you are setting it in the SQL query with `'node' AS field_data_my_field_node_entity_type`.

If your question is how to get the entity type for a node, that is always *node*; there isn't a field in the "nodes" table that contains that value.

If you added a "field_data_my_field_node_entity_type" field to one or more content types, and you want to get the content of that field, you need to follow these steps, since the content of node fields is not contained in the "node" table.

- Get the node ID of the nodes
- Load the nodes with `node_load()`

```php
$result = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE ((status = :status) AND (type IN  (:type)) ORDER BY created DESC', array(':status'=>'1', ':type'=>'_my_content_type'))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row) {
  $node = node_load($row['nid']);
  // Access the field as $node->field_data_my_field_node_entity_type.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean I have to make a whole lot more queries?  Is it not possible to get that value from the query?

Comment: There are many hooks involved when getting the value of a node field (one created with the field API), and those hooks would not be invoked when you simply query the database. Apart that, the code I shown surely works in every case and for every Drupal version. The number of queries doesn't increase too much.